# How to check if included file from a loop comes with errors

Tags: php, loops, try-catch

I have this kind of loop. On each iteration it should include a file, Included files can come with errors. Once some of included files gets an error the whole process of getting lost. How to prevent breaking of the process?
I tried this try catch but it errors from included files still cause stopping execution of file.
Thanks

```
foreach ($li_arrays as $index => $li_array) {
    if($index == 0){

        try {
            require 'update.php';
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Exception caught with message: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }

    }
    elseif ($index == 1){
        try {
            require 'update1.php';
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Exception caught with message: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
    }else{
        try {
            require 'update2.php';
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Exception caught with message: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Simply use `include` instead of `require`

Comment: What do you mean with "Included files can come with errors"? If those files contain syntax errors, _then fix those errors_ !

Comment: I hope you do not attempt to implement a setup where you execute php files you have no control over? Like files uploaded by clients? That would be a _mile wide security gap_ ... Anyone could do anything with your system.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I changed "require" with "include" and used this try-catch approach inside each included file.

```
$attempts = 0;

    do {
        try
        {
           ////PHP code ///
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "\n\n======EXCEPTION======\n\n";
            var_dump($e);
            $attempts++;
            sleep(30);
            continue;
        }
        break;
    } while($attempts < 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Errors in php are not recoverable, so they will always lead to the termination of your script.

I am not even sure that you are even talking about Errors, though if you are, this is the answer to your question.

Another thing to be aware of:
Require will throw an E_COMPILE_ERROR if the required file doesn't exist, which is also something you won't be able to catch.
If you don't want to terminate if the script isn't found, use include instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'll replace "require" with "include". I'll try to catch exceptions inside those files.

Comment: @Geobo depending on the context of what you are trying to do, there might be another possible alternative to include:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php
(executing an external script)
If the external script terminates because of an error, this doesn't automatically lead to a termination of the calling script.